# PHP error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: php, bash, terminal, popen, codesign

I have a code resign script which is working well when I run it from the terminal.
Exactly there is a codesign command in the script file that runs well in the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "$EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" "$DYLIB"
```

If I run the same script file from PHP, it will give me this error message:

> error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

Please help me 
thank you

Comment: You can log the arguments that are passed into the script in both cases and see if there is any difference. Consider also running with `set -x` and piping out to a log file, at least until you can understand what is different about the invocations. I have a feeling that the arguments are not being passed in as you expect, perhaps because those environment variables are not being setup correctly in the process that is exec'd.

Comment: I recommend you to add the PHP code, especially around the line where you get the error. This will help us to identify the cause.

Comment: Thank you for replies, I am running script via php popen that is  $proc            = popen("$cmd  2>&1 ; echo Exit status : $?", 'r'); the script is same as https://github.com/vtky/resign/blob/master/resign/scripts/resign.sh

Comment: To Jameson: arguments are well passed. i think php can't run codesign command properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the privilege problem, _www can't access